# How can I fit an image to view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an application where users can take photos horizontal o vertically, and then, the images are displayed in a gallery on a webpage, and if I click on one, it expands and displays with a `Modal`.

My problem is that images that are taken horizontally look smaller since I am using `max-width: 30vw`, but vertical images are show perfectly.

How can I adapt the horizontal images to have more width but not affect photos that are taken vertically?

The images are dynamic, so I can't use classes to tell some to take x amount of px or vw and others another amount.

this is my .css for the images:

```
.modal-content{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 30vw;
    max-height:85vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

And this my modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDownload" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
```

This is Vertical image:

[image]

This horizontal:

[image]

This is my Javascript:

```
function AgrandaOpenModalr(img) {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    var btnDownload = document.getElementById('btnDownload');

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = img.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = " ";
    btnDownload.href = img.src;
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an actual example of the issue? Like create a code snippet that shows several photos, vertical and horizontal. It's hard to visualize what you're saying with just the code shown.

Comment: Let me try it, I don´t know how to upload a photo into a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume it's alsways the same model that is loaded, but the `src` is dynamicly changed when the modal is opened to associate with the correct picture. Is that how it works?

And you've stated that you can't work with an extra class right?

So maybe it's an idea to call a Javascript function when the modal is shown? With some kind of an eventListener of added with an onclick or something?

When the function below is executed it changes the max-width of the image accordingly.

```
// The methodcall you want to execute when the modal opens
setModalWidth();

// The method that will change the maxWidth accordingly
function setModalWidth() {
   let img = document.querySelector('.modal-content');

   if(img.naturalWidth > img.naturalHeight){
      img.style.maxWidth = '50vw';
   } else {
      img.style.maxWidth = '30vw';
   }
}
```

### EDIT

So a specific method as suggested above will work, but as you've posted the script you're already using it is ofcourse also possible to include the code in that function.

Let me show you

```
function AgrandaOpenModalr(img) {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    var btnDownload = document.getElementById('btnDownload');

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = img.src;
    
    // the added if-statement to change the max-width    
    if(modalImg.naturalWidth > modalImg.naturalHeight){
      modalImg.style.maxWidth = '50vw';
    } else {
      modalImg.style.maxWidth = '30vw';
    }

    captionText.innerHTML = " ";
    btnDownload.href = img.src;
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it, I added my Javascript code to show what I'm doing

Comment: Great! so you could add the complete function from my first answer below the `function AgrandaOpenModalr(img){}` and add the methodcall `setModalWidth()` somewhere in your current function (just before you start with the close-part). Or you can just add the if-statement to your current function as I did in the EDIT part of the post. Hope this helps you.